# mysqli comma separator in result list

Tags: php

I have the folowing query:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT name FROM table LIMIT 5");
```

I want to have a list of these names either with the comma or as a list one above another.

```
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
echo '.$result->name.';
}
```

How can I do that.

Thanks

Comment: Use `ul` and `li` and why are you using `.` at the end and the beginning?

Comment: I can not use it because that is a listing inside of a <li> in the title of it

Comment: Then use nested lists. This IS a list, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the list with names comma separated try

```
$list='';
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
$list.= $result->name.',';
}

echo $list;
```

here you will get the one trailing comma at end of list, if you want to remove than do

```
echo $list=substr($list,0,-1);
```

Comment: i am getting one one two times in the results although I do not have it in results

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what you do with these dots there.

```
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
    echo $result->name . ', ';
}
```

If you want it below each other:

```
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
    echo $result->name . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: This will leave a stray comma at the end, and you will have to use `rtrim()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [];
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
    $arr[] = $result->name;
}
echo implode(",", $arr);
```

This will add the results to an array, then join the results on a comma.

If you want a list then you can use

```
echo "<ul><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $arr) . "</li></ul>;
```

Answer (score 0):

List:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT name FROM table LIMIT 5");
echo "<ul>";
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<li>$result->name</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comma:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT name FROM table LIMIT 5");
$names = array();
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
    $names[] = $result->name;
}
echo implode(', ', $names);
```